# How to send photo in telegram bot in php 7.0.2

Tags: bots, php-7, telegram-bot, php-curl, php-telegram-bot

I have created a simple project to test sending photo to telegram bot in php 7, but nothing sends after starting the bot, however this project runs in php 5.3!
Is there anything different in php 7 that I should use it?

```
$message = file_get_contents("php://input");
$result = json_decode($message,true);
$token = "My_Robot_token";

if($result['message']['text']=='/start')
{
   $target_url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/sendPhoto";
   $file_path = "./img/img1.jpg";
   $file_name_with_full_path = realpath($file_path);
   $chat_id = $result['message']['chat']['id'];
   $photo_send = array(
      'chat_id'   => $chat_id,
      'photo'  => '@'.$file_name_with_full_path,
      'caption'   => 'photo sent!'
   );
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $photo_send);
   $result=curl_exec ($ch);
   file_put_contents('res.txt', $ch);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
define('API_KEY','API Token');

function bot($method,$datas=[]){
    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . API_KEY . "/" . $method;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$datas);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_error($ch)){
        var_dump(curl_error($ch));
    }else{
        return json_decode($res);
    }
}

function sendphoto($ChatId, $photo, $caption){
    bot('sendphoto',[
        'chat_id'=>$ChatId,
        'photo'=>$photo,
        'caption'=>$caption
    ]);
}

$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
var_dump($update);

$message=$update->message;
$chat_id=$message->chat->id;
$text =$message->text;

if ($text=='/start'){
    sendphoto($chat_id,"Your file_id","photo sent!"); // send photo by file_id
    sendphoto($chat_id,new CURLFILE("file path"),"photo sent!"); // send photo by url
}
```

Comment: at least explain your problem.